# JQuery Draggable Cancel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm trying to cancel 1 css class, which is working fine, and 2 inputs at the same time. But i can only get the css class canceled..

How can this be fixed ?

```
$("#move").mousedown(function () {
    $( "#draggable").draggable({cancel : '.scroll',
                                cancel : 'input'
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 2 issues:

1. `{cancel : '.scroll',cancel : 'input'}` is not a valid [javascript object literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php) because youre using 2 properties with the same name.
2. You're initializing your dragable element on each mousedown but you need to do this only at the begining of your code.

Try using [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#draggable").draggable({cancel : '.scroll,input'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below method.

cancel : '.scroll,input'